# Cell date via script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

```
function archivr() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Página1');
  sh.getRange('A2').setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-3", "YYYY-MM-DD"));
}
```

I'm trying to use this script format to put today's date in my spreadsheet, but when I try to put it, the result is:

```
2020-02-52
```

Day 52? There is no logic to this, I don't know what's going on.

Additional, how can I also add tomorrow's date in A3?

Comment: Kindly ask new/additional questions in a  different post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)), `D` is Day in year. Use `dd` instead.